# Insert Temp Table Failing with Parsing Error on Exec

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I want to insert the result set coming from a query into a temporary table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse. I used the below statements but I am getting a parse error:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(1000)
CREATE taBLE #TempTable (L NVARCHAR(100))
SET @SQL2 = 'SELECT Col1 FROM Table1'
INSERT INTO #TempTable (L) EXEC SQL2***
```

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
> Parse error at line: 5, column: 28: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.

I even tried `Declare @T TABLE (ID iNT)` still getting a parse error.

Comment: `EXEC SQL2` will try to execute a procedure called `SQL2`. You want to execute the "dynamic" statement: `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2;`

Comment: Of course, the real question is why use the above syntax at all; the value in `@SQL2` isn't dynamic, so why not just `INSERT INTO #TempTable (L) SELECT Col1 FROM Table1;`?

Answer (score 0):

I got answer minutes after uploading the question

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support INSERT ... EXEC

For explanation and an alternative approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-stored-procedures#insertexecute

Comment: If you are using Azure SQL Warehouse, you should really tell us that in the question. Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Data Warehouse are *not* the same thing.